# Human Interface Device (HID) in Xamarin/Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, hid

I am attempting to develop a app to comunicate with bluetooth LE crossplataform. To do it, I'm trying to start with xamarin.forms and using 2 samples groups

- A sample of android App by Microchips and Monkey.robotic
- A sample of UWP project to connect by HID (I have a device to do it as a dongle service)

The sample of microsoft was:
https://github.com/oldnewthing/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess

I'll use a Conditional Compilation to do both situations, but when I try to use it into Xamarin there are troubles around  some UWP references that didn't work , it is not compatible with xamarin and several await/async errors.

When I try to force by the other side (like .NET Standard 1.6) it didn't work either.

**What is really compatible with (xamarin/xamarin.forms)2.+ ?**

**Is it possible to do, a HID connection using xamarin.forms design?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HID project should be referenced by UWP project. In PCL(Xamarin.Forms) project, you should use DependencyService to use that 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/

Comment: Thank you sir, I did.

I organize my HID in code behind of UWP project in a net standart (New PCL). It is using dependencyService to send short commands to views and using messagingcenter to "callback" my events to views.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this pattern. I.e Dependency Services. In my opinion, they are actually anti dependency injection. The idea of dependency injection in my opinion, is that when you instantiate some object that requires some other polymorphous object, it is constructed with this dependency. Dependency Services break this rule because when an object depends on another object, it may or may not be instantiated at the static level. A common problem with dependency services that I see is that people forget to instantiate the class on some platforms with NotImplementedException.

Comment: I used HID to acess a bluetooth module for old PCs of my clients. In this case dependency service looks like a way to create a "black box" for the peripherical functions ... the connection button only create a new estance of HIDdevice class and than I create all process in code behind, similar that I'll use others system, but there (android and MAC) I'll use native bluetooth to acess and populate my share buttons/design .

Comment: Great. Any luck with Android or Mac? Hid.Net has all the code you need for Android, but I need examples of how to connect to Hid on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to connect to a Hid device with Xamarin on UWP and Android. Xamarin.Forms is a UI library. It doesn't have anything to do with Hid connection, but any Android or UWP app using Xamarin.Forms can connect to a Hid device.

Here is a Xamarin.Forms sample that connects to a Hid device:

Shared library:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Trezor.Net/tree/master/src/Trezor.Net.XamarinFormsSample/Trezor.Net.XamarinFormsSample

Android:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Trezor.Net/tree/master/src/Trezor.Net.XamarinFormsSample/XFAS

UWP:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Trezor.Net/tree/master/src/Trezor.Net.XamarinFormsSample/Trezor.Net.XamarinFormsSample.UWP

The base library designed for Xamarin that is used to connect to the devices is called Hid.Net https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net.

Comment: Thank you for samples ... I already done, but I'll check to improve my code :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Any chance you could show me your code so I can see how you solved the problem?